# Float to whole integer keeping digits after decimal

Tags: ruby

I have a float that has eight digits after the decimal. I want to convert this to a whole number/integer, keeping the digits after the decimal. For example: my float is `0.06870697`, and I want it to be `006870697`.

Everything I've tried so far removes all the digits after the decimal.

Comment: `0.06870697.to_s.gsub('.','')` :D

Comment: `006870697` doesn't look like a number to me. It looks like a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution is solving problem for the number in the question. You can do as follows.

```
value = 0.06870697

value.to_s.delete('.')

=> "006870697"
```

Comment: Consider what happens for `0.0603` instead.

Comment: @tadman 0.0603 float number result is '00603'. I did not understand why you said that.

Comment: It's because the intent was to have a fixed number of places in the output.

Comment: @tadman I understood you but Peter says that "I have a float that has eight digits after the decimal." So, it doesn't matter that there is how many number after comma.

Comment: `0.00005000` has "eight digits after the decimal" if expressed that way, but when displayed the trailing zeroes are trimmed off.

Comment: @tadman you are right. Actually my answer is solving this question but not general solution. Should I erase or edit this answer? What do you think? You are more experienced in Stackoverflow.

Comment: There's a few interesting solutions here. If you think you can come up with one that's different but also works under those circumstances, no harm in editing to show other options. If not, no shame in deleting one that didn't work out. I've had to do that many, many times before.

Comment: @tadman I have edited my solution. Thanks for the mentorship.

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply it to shift the digits, then use a `printf`-style formatter:

```
v = 0.06870697

'%09d' % (v * 10e7)
# => "006870697"
```

Multiplying a value by `10e7` (10 x 10<sup>7</sup> = 10<sup>8</sup>) shifts the decimal place eight digits to the right.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Right you are, adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as tadman's but below versions seems working -))

1.

```
a = 0.06870697
a.to_s.split(".").join("")
```

2.

```
a.to_s.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
```

3.

```
a.to_s.slice! "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
val = 0.06870697

num = (val * 10 ** 8).to_i.to_s

num.rjust(9, '0')

=> "006870697"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the decimal point eight digits to the right by multiplying by `10^8`.

```
(0.06870697 * 10 ** 8).to_i
# => 6870697
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.